# Use Redux module inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a module A built in react-redux. A is the parent component name which looks somewhat like

```
const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <A />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('id'));
```

Inside component A there is a component C.js which has a **connect** function

A.js

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <C />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

C.js

```
render() {
return(<div>SomeCode</div>
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(C);
```

There is another B.js file which is a ReactComponent (no redux used here). It has its own state.

I want to use the component A inside B's render method something like

```
import A from '/path'

render() {
return (<A/>)
}
```

While doing so I am getting an error.

**Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(C)".
Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to 
and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(C) in connect options.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You did not provide code for C, A, and index.js.

Comment: added @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: In c component you did not define `mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: yes those are already there. Its a pre existing working code.

Comment: Are you by chance using a third-party renderer, something to draw graphs for example? Those often break context.

Comment: @phry no. We are not using anything of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

I modified parent and exported it as following

```
render(){
return(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <A />
    </Provider>
);}
```

Importing A worked fine